# Datepicker value to search through table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a datepicker widget attached to a search textbox called **#searchess**, the search textbox is supposed to search table **#esstable** with whatever date is in the textbox. However, when i pick a date from datepicker, the date gets into the textbox but doesn't search the table until i type something.

```
<script>

          $(function() {
                $( "#searchess" ).datepicker({
                 dateFormat: " yy-mm-dd"
                });
            });

        $("#searchess").keyup(function() {
        var value = this.value;

            $("#esstable").find("tr").each(function(index) {
                if (!index) return;
                var id = $(this).find("td").first().text();
                $(this).toggle(id.indexOf(value) !== -1);
                });
            });

</script>
```

Here's my **#searchess** textbox search:

```
<input type="text" id="searchess" placeholder="ESS Date Search"></input>
```

Here's the table:

```
<div id="esstable">
             <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>ESS File</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td> 2014-03-17 </td>
                      <td> <a href="./file1"> file ex1</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td> 2013-03-17 </td>
                      <td> <a href="./file2"> file ex2</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your search is triggered from a keyup event and the calendar doesn't trigger that when you pick a date. But you can add that functionality with:

```
$("#searchess").datepicker({
    dateFormat: " yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function () {
        $("#searchess").trigger('keyup')
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8N5w4/)**